# AngularJS custom directive is not loading correct path when working with MVC

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

How to work with AngularJS custom directive in MVC5.
I have a requirement where I have to create a directive and use it in MVC5 view.
I have given template URL in something like `~/script/path/test.html` but as MVC routing is like `http://localhost/deliverable` it searches for html file as `http://localhost/deliverable/script/path/test.html` but actual location of file is `http://localhost/script/path/test.html`. Please advise.

Comment: Did you tried with ../script/path/test.html

Comment: Have you tried /script/path/test.html?

Comment: Hi I tried both ways but didnt work.